# How to prove law of large numbers doesn't hold

Tags: probability, law-of-large-numbers

I'm reading Feller's *An introduction to Probability theory and Its Application*. I don't know how to prove when lln doesn't hold. I just know that the sufficient condition for the lln to hold is that $\sqrt{Var(S_n)}/n \rightarrow 0$.
For example: Let {$X_k$} be mutually independent and have a common distribution
with mean $\mu$ and finite variance. If $S_n = X_1 + \cdots + X_k$, prove that lln does not  hold for the sequence {$S_n$} but holds for $a_nS_n$ if $na_n \rightarrow 0$.
What should i do know?

Comment: Are you sure $a_nn\to 0$?

Comment: @WilliamM. yeah

Comment: I think you need $\mu=0$ because otherwise $\mathbb{E}[S_n]=n\mu$, so with $Y_n:=\frac{1}{n}(S_1+\ldots+S_n)$, we have $\mathbb{E}[Y_n]=(n+1)\mu$. This doesn't necessarily prevent $Y_n-(n+1)\mu$ converging in probability to some constant, but it does mean that $Y_n$ can't converge in probability to any finite number. Otherwise, you were right about the problems with my answer.